# Using an HTML table for layout in HTML5

Tags: html, layout, html-table

I'm currently upgrading a MediaWiki installation from ancient 1.6.10 to 1.19.2. One of the changes is that the new MediaWiki uses `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which changes the layout a bit.

Now one of the MediaWiki extensions uses tables for layout. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<table>
 <tr style="background-color:lime;">
  <td><img src="pixel.gif"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Now even though the pixel.gif is only 1x1 pixel large, the lime rectangle uses 3x22 pixels. My intention was that the row should only be 1 pixel high. Is there a simple way using `<table>`, or do I have to switch to using `<div>`s?

Comment: Why do you want to stick with tables for layouts, the cons over-weigh the pros - big time.

Comment: Thanks for upgrading. :) It's always a pain to see MediaWiki wikis running ten years old code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css: `td { font-size:0;padding:0 }`

This has nothing to do with tables really. You'll get the same problem with a div. So similarly for that, use `div { font-size:0; }`. More realistically, You need to qualify which divs you want styling like that with a class. e.g `div.myimagecontainer { font-size:0; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Tables are tables and html and are no different with HTML5 but, of course, tables should never be used for layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `<table>` for layout then make sure you properly set the role attribute `<table role="presentation">` by following the W3C html5 recommendation:

> Tables should not be used as layout aids. Historically, many Web
>   authors have tables in HTML as a way to control their page layout
>   making it difficult to extract tabular data from such documents. In
>   particular, users of accessibility tools, like screen readers, are
>   likely to find it very difficult to navigate pages with tables used
>   for layout. If a table is to be used for layout it must be marked with
>   the attribute role="presentation" for a user agent to properly
>   represent the table to an assistive technology and to properly convey
>   the intent of the author to tools that wish to extract tabular data
>   from the document.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element